# Trying to transform a button color when clicked flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm not sure if I'm using this transform correctly. I'm trying to lock in a color adjustment on a button when it has been clicked once.  I tried starting off adjusting the alpha=0, and it worked ok. I'm not very good with as3 so a little help would be very nice.

I get this error: "ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property colorTransform on flash.display.SimpleButton.
    at movie_fla::MainTimeline/onMouseClickEvent()"

Thanks Terry

```
stop();
this.wheelsMain.inner4.Inner1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);

function onMouseClickEvent(event:Event) {

  Object(this).wheelsMain.inner4.Inner1btn.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0,0);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the "transform" property...

like this:

```
stop();

this.wheelsMain.inner4.Inner1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);

function onMouseClickEvent(event:Event) {

  event.target.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0,0);
  }
```

whatch the example at the bottom of [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html)

- You can shorten the code with "event.target" which points to the button directly!

Good Luck!!

EDIT:
* If I helped you - please mark as answered!

Comment: Thanks for your help Yitschak! Take Care